# X-axis labels(Date) is not coming properly D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on line chart using d3 v4 version. X-axis label is date(only Year). X-axis labels are not coming properly .

Its overlapping with each other. I just want to display year in x-aaxis labels. I tried with d3.timeparse still values are not coming correct.

Help me to know the issue.

codepen link -https://codepen.io/pinkisharma/pen/oyPzWW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->     
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    initLineChart();
    function initLineChart(){
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // parse the date / time
        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");
        var data =[{"date":"2014","EPS":"34.13","EBITDA":"34.12"},{"date":"2015","EPS":"63.98","EBITDA":"45.56"},{"date":"2016","EPS":"67.00","EBITDA":"54.00"},
                  {"date":"2017","EPS":"45.00","EBITDA":"22.17"},{"date":"2018","EPS":"18.32","EBITDA":"24.13"}];
        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


        // define the 1st line
        var valueline = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.EBITDA); });

        // define the 2nd line
        var valueline2 = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.EPS); });

        // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
        // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
        // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Get the data
          // format the data
          data.forEach(function(d) {
              d.date = parseTime(d.date);
              d.EBITDA = +d.EBITDA;
              d.EPS = +d.EPS;
          });

          // Scale the range of the data
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
              return Math.max(d.EBITDA, d.EPS); })]);

          // Add the valueline path.
          svg.append("path")
              .data([data])
              .attr("class", "line")
              .style("stroke", "#00357F")
              .style("fill", "none")
              .style("stroke-width", "3px")
              .attr("d", valueline);

          // Add the valueline2 path.
          svg.append("path")
              .data([data])
              .attr("class", "line")
              .style("stroke", "#006600")
              .style("fill", "none")
              .style("stroke-width", "3px")
              .attr("d", valueline2);

          // Add the X Axis
          svg.append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

          // Add the Y Axis
          svg.append("g")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
         // Add the scatterplot
          svg.selectAll("dot")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("r", 5)
              .style("fill", "#00357F")
              .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.EBITDA); });
        // Add the scatterplot
          svg.selectAll("dot")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("r", 5)
              .style("fill", "#006600")
              .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.EPS); });


    }

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.ticks(n)` to hint the axis renderer on the approximate number of ticks to draw. Since you want to display the ticks once per year, instead of trying to manually figure out the value of `n` yourself, you can use `d3.timeYear.every(1)`<sup>1</sup> to calculate the number of years.

p/s: Additional tip: since you are only concerned about displaying the year, you might also want to use `.tickFormat()` to ensure that only the year gets displayed:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1)));
```

```js
initLineChart();

function initLineChart() {
  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 40,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // parse the date / time
  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");
  var data = [{
      "date": "2014",
      "EPS": "34.13",
      "EBITDA": "34.12"
    }, {
      "date": "2015",
      "EPS": "63.98",
      "EBITDA": "45.56"
    }, {
      "date": "2016",
      "EPS": "67.00",
      "EBITDA": "54.00"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017",
      "EPS": "45.00",
      "EBITDA": "22.17"
    }, {
      "date": "2018",
      "EPS": "18.32",
      "EBITDA": "24.13"
    }
  ];
  // set the ranges
  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


  // define the 1st line
  var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.EBITDA);
    });

  // define the 2nd line
  var valueline2 = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.EPS);
    });

  // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
  // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
  // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Get the data
  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.EBITDA = +d.EBITDA;
    d.EPS = +d.EPS;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return Math.max(d.EBITDA, d.EPS);
  })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "#00357F")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
    .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the valueline2 path.
  svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "#006600")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
    .attr("d", valueline2);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1)));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  // Add the scatterplot
  svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "#00357F")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.EBITDA);
    });
  // Add the scatterplot
  svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "#006600")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.EPS);
    });


}
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Footnotes:

1. See the use of [`d3.timeYear()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#timeYear) and [`interval.every()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_every)

Comment: Thanks @Terry...This is exactly what i want. :-)

Comment: could you please guide me how can i add data points over the dots?